# Selecting color when hovering over navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, colors

So I have this navigation bar that I want to change the color of when hovering over with the mouse. Its default is black, I want it to be lightgrey-white. What have I done wrong here?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Frontend</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box">
                <div id="header">
                    <br />
                    <div id="searchMenu">
                        <input id="sweBtn" type="button" value="SVENSKA" />
                        <input id="engBtn" type="button" value="ENGLISH" />
                        <input id="searchTxt" type="text" />
                        <input id="searchBtn" type="button" value="SÖK" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-left" id="imgText">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                    <p>Paragraph</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img id="imgHeader" src="~/img/Header.png" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul id="navBar"> //Here is the navbar I am talking about
                        <li><a>BEHÖVER DU AVOKAT?</a></li>
                        <li><a>ADVOKATETIK</a></li>
                        <li><a>ATT BLI ADVOKAT</a></li>
                        <li><a>UTBILDNING</a></li>
                        <li><a>ADVOKATSSAMFUNDET TYCKER</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>

<link href="~/Content/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
        }

#header {
    background-color: #503F31;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px;
}

#searchMenu {
    margin-left: 1450px;
}

#sweBtn {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: grey;
}

#engBtn {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: gold;
}

#searchTxt {
    background-color: grey;
    border-color: grey;
}

#searchBtn {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: gold;
}

#imgText {
    font-size: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}

#imgHeader {
    width: 1904px;
}

#navBar {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    color: gold;
    background-color: #503F31;
}

#footer {
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: -250px;
}

*::selection { /*This should handle the hover color situation right?*/
  background: #cc0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
*::-moz-selection {
  background: #cc0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
*::-webkit-selection {
  background: #cc0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Also a sidenote: I want for every listitem to be seperated with a vertical line like this: "|"

Comment: So where is your hover CSS rule?

Comment: *::selection { /*This should handle the hover color situation right?*/
  background: #cc0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}

Comment: Nope, that's a completely different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `li a:hover` background-color to `#CCC` and remove this:

```
*::selection { /*This should handle the hover color situation right?*/
  background: #cc0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
*::-moz-selection {
   background: #cc0000;
   color: #ffffff;
}
*::-webkit-selection {
   background: #cc0000;
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

I'm assuming your `#111` isn't 'black' but 'blackish' and therefore, seen as black ;).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this blocks:

```
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* Separator Border */
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

li a:hover {
    /* Background color on hover */
    background-color: silver;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Final css:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: silver;
    color: #fff;
}

#header {
    background-color: #503F31;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px;
}

#searchMenu {
    margin-left: 1450px;
}

#sweBtn {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: grey;
}

#engBtn {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: gold;
}

#searchTxt {
    background-color: grey;
    border-color: grey;
}

#searchBtn {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: gold;
}

#imgText {
    font-size: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}

#imgHeader {
    width: 1904px;
}

#navBar {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    color: gold;
    background-color: #503F31;
}

#footer {
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: -250px;
}

*::selection { /*This should handle the hover color situation right?*/
  background: #cc0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
*::-moz-selection {
  background: #cc0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
*::-webkit-selection {
  background: #cc0000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding braces:

```
li a:hover {{background-color: #111;}}
```

Comment: That's no valid CSS.